# how to apply a matlab fit function to every row of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, curve-fitting

I need to fit with the fourier function every successive row of the matrix avoiding to use `for` loop. I tried to use a cell array but have no idea how to use it with fit. 
My program is

```
I=imread('test.tif','tif');  
I=double(I);  
nat=num2cell(I,1);  
wy_I=cellfun(@size,nat, 'UniformOutput', false);  
we_I=cellfun(@(x)1:x(1), wy_I, 'UniformOutput', false);  
wyn=cellfun(@(x,y)fit(x',y,'fourier1'), we_I, nat);
```

It gives `??? Error using ==> cellfun cfit type is not currently implemented.` probably cell array is not a solution for this problem.
How to solve this problem?
Thanks

**Update**

```
wyn=cellfun(@(x,y)fit(x',y,'fourier1'), we_I, nat, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

works without errors but wyn have only empty cells
I test it for one row

```
j=cell2mat(we_I(1,1))  
k=cell2mat(nat(1,1))  
z=fit(j',k,'fourier1')
```

and `z` contains good values for model
I do something wrong with syntax in cellfun but have not idea what

Comment: Fitting a function to every row of an image is a perfectly fine use of a `for`-loop. All you'll get with the call to `cellfun` is a loss of readability, but there won't be any noticeable gain of performance.

Answer (score 1):

The [FIT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/fit.html) function returns an object of type [`cfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/curvefit/cfit.html) in this example. The error would appear to suggest that [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) is unable to collect these objects into an array of type `cfit` to return as an output. I would instead try returning a *cell array* of `cfit` objects by adding `'UniformOutput',false` to the last line as well.

Comment: thx for help setting     UniformOutput works fine for error but     cellfun return a empty cell array

Comment: @bartek: Strange, it works fine for me (MATLAB R2010b). What version are you using? Is your image 2-D or 3-D?